# How do I test the maximum TCP/IP transfer rates of my computer?

Tags: performance, tcpip, tcp

In Delphi, I am writing client software for open source message brokers, and would like the transfer rates with a realistic upper limit of what can be achieved on my local computer, or between my computer and a remote server in my network.

Is there a simple tool for Windows and/or Linux which continuously sends and receives many simple TCP/IP messages of a defined size, and shows current statistics like messages/second, MB/second?

I know that I could write it myself, but maybe the answer is also helpful for non-programmers :)

Answer (score 1):

I think [iperf](http://iperf.sourceforge.net/) can do what you want. A win32 binary is available [here](http://mayoxide.com/iperf/).

Answer (score 0):

There is TTCP / [PACTTCP](http://www.pcausa.com/Utilities/pcattcp.htm)

> Test TCP (TTCP) is a command-line sockets-based benchmarking tool for
>   measuring TCP and UDP performance between two systems.